# How to handle expandable menu in breadcrumbs?

Tags: menu, breadcrumbs

There is a sidebar menu. Some menu items can be expanded and can contain child items. 

As a user, you go to **Settings** and then **General**. Since there are no such a page as **Settings**, the breadcrumbs would show you **Dashboard / General**.
The problem is that if you close the menu, the breadcrumbs **Dashboard / General** will not give you enough information on which part of the site you are currently located.

How to handle expandable menu items with breadcrumbs so the user always knows his location?

[image]

Comment: You could add the Settings to the breadcrumbs so its:
Dashboard / Settings / General

Or you could do it like this:
Dashboard / General settings
Dashboard / Privacy settings

etc.

Comment: @PectoralisMajor If I add **Dashboard / Settings / General**, there must be a page **Settings** which will be shown when you press **Settings** in breadcrumbs. But there are no such a page.

Comment: What is the actual title of the page? So for accessibility purposes I assume a screenreader wouldn't just read out the `<title>` of being 'General'. And the H1 wouldn't just say 'General'. You need to name your pages a bit better and then this is less of an issue. 'General Settings' is better (but then just using the word 'general' isn't that intuitive). Basically, name your pages useful names. If this is a page directly off the Home then it'll be 'Dashboard / General Settings'

Answer (score 5):

Simply rename the breadcrumb and (ideally) the title of the page from **General** to **General Settings**

Same goes for the rest: *Privacy Settings, Notification Settings, Content Settings*

Currently, the user sees the word **General** as the page title which is vague and confusing even with side menu open. The users shouldn't have to depend on the side-menu to realize where they are. The title and the breadcrumb kind of have that **EXACT** purpose (to make the user aware of where he/she is)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "dashboard" word in breadcrumbs and put the Settings word. If the user click in Settings breadcrumb the sidemenu comes back again with the current page pre-selected or highlighted.

Also is possible to add a grouped button with a independent dropdown button and link the General page to Settings level.[image]

Comment: Are you suggesting that the breadcrumb triggers a side-menu to open? That's an interesting idea, but I've never seen that happen before anywhere. Do you know if this actually works well for users? Have you seen it before?

Comment: The breadcrumbs is an location indicator of user within the app hierarchy  but since that page doesn't exist that link can guide the user where that level lives (sidemenu) and show the underneath options from the Settings Group.